# AngularJS - Communicate between views belonging to the same state ui-router

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router

I am working on an AngularJS project, and I am using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to generate nested views. I have one state generating multiple views.

My question is : how can I communicate and send data between views? 
I have googled a lot and I am still stucked by that issue. I have used `$rootscope`, `$brodcast` and `$on`, but I don't think it's a best practice.

Any help please? Thank you very much.

Comment: use factory or services

Answer (score 1):

Passing data between nested views is no different than passing data between any other two views. There are two basic scenarios to build from. If these views are using the same controller then your problem is no problem at all, and you can pass the same $scope to both views. If your views are using different controllers then really the problem is how to pass data between two controllers, regardless of the views.

Passing data between two or more controllers is easy to accomplish by housing the data in a provider, such as a factory, and then including that factory as a dependency to each controller than needs to access the data.

Here is a simple example:

**View 1** (Assigned Ctrl1 through route congif)

```
<div>
    <h1>View 2</h1>
    <p>{{data.value}}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller 1**

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function($scope, myFactory){
    $scope.data = myFactory.data;
}]);
```

**View 2** (Assigned Ctrl2 through route congif)

```
<div>
    <h1>View 2</h1>
    <p>{{data.value}}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller 2**

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function($scope, myFactory){
    $scope.data = myFactory.data;
}]);
```

and finally your **Factory**

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function(){
    return {
        data: {
           value: 'some data'
        }
    }
});
```